# Passing function's data to another function

Tags: vbscript, parameter-passing

How can I pass the data generated by the `EliminaAcentos` function to the 
`URLEncode` function in this script?

The first function removes diacritics and the second function URL-encodes the data.

```
Function EliminaAcentos(texto)
    Dim i, s1, s2
    s1 = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü"
    s2 = "AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUaaaaaaceeeeiiiiooooouuuu"
    If Len(texto) <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(s1)
            texto = Replace(texto, Mid(s1,i,1), Mid(s2,i,1))
        Next
    End If

    EliminaAcentos = texto
End Function

Function URLEncode(ByVal str)
    Dim strTemp, strChar
    Dim intPos, intASCII
    strTemp = ""
    strChar = ""

    For intPos = 1 To Len(str)
        intASCII = Asc(Mid(str, intPos, 1))
        If intASCII = 32 Then
            strTemp = strTemp & "+"
        ElseIf ((intASCII < 123) And (intASCII > 96)) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Chr(intASCII)
        ElseIf ((intASCII < 91) And (intASCII > 64)) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Chr(intASCII)
        ElseIf ((intASCII < 58) And (intASCII > 47)) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Chr(intASCII)
        Else
            strChar = Trim(Hex(intASCII))
            If intASCII < 16 Then
                strTemp = strTemp & "%0" & strChar
            Else
                strTemp = strTemp & "%" & strChar
            End If
        End If
    Next

    URLEncode = strTemp
End Function

WScript.Echo URLEncode(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

Comment: `URLEncode( EliminaAcentos( WScript.Arguments(0)))` but  ensure that `EliminaAcentos` function declaration should be `Function EliminaAcentos( ByVal texto)`

Comment: I put this in the end of the script, but is not working (I did the ByVal texto) too.
Wscript.Echo URLEncode( EliminaAcentos( WScript.Arguments(0)))

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are two ways to go about it:

- You can nest the call of `EliminaAcentos` in the call of `URLEncode` as [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911301/passing-function%c2%b4s-data-to-another-function-in-vbscript#comment63275013_37911301) suggested:

  ```
  URLEncode(EliminaAcentos(WScript.Arguments(0)))
  ```
- You can embed the call of `EleminaAcentos` in the body of the `URLEncode` function:

  ```
  Function URLEncode(ByVal str)
      Dim strTemp, strChar
      Dim intPos, intASCII
      strTemp = ""
      strChar = ""

      str = EliminaAcentos(str)
      For intPos = 1 To Len(str)
          ...
      Next

      URLEncode = strTemp
  End Function
  ```

Usually you'd pick the first option if there are situations where you call `URLEncode` and don't want diacritics removed, or if you don't control the implementation of `URLEncode`. If you always want `URLEncode` to remove diacritics and you control the function implementation you'd pick the second option.

---

Side note (also mentioned by @JosefZ): pass the parameter to `EliminaAcentos` by value, so the function call doesn't inadvertently modify the original value.

```
Function EliminaAcentos(ByVal texto)
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help !  I´m using your second example (embed call), and it´s working fine :-)